# Issue in applying Date filter on collection

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, collection, customer-address, date

I have an attribute with code "open_date", for customer address. data is being saved in db in format **29/01/2017**, I am trying to apply filter to get store opening in next two weeks. What I have tried is

```
$fromDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('d/m/Y');//    06/01/2017
$toDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+2 week"));//             20/01/2017

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('from' => $fromDate, true));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('to' => $toDate, true));
```

and also

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
```

and also

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('gteq' => $fromDate));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('lteq' => $toDate));
```

And have tried some other methods.

```
$coutn = count($collection);
$ids = $collection->getAllIds();
```

count and ids have not correct records. with above dates, count should be two(2), but it has 10 in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');

$fromdate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($data['date'],Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT, null, false);
$from = $fromdate->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$todate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($data['date'],Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT, null, false);
$todate->addWeek('1');
$to = $todate->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to));
```

Comment: The key here is to use `Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT` and not `'d/m/Y'` so that MySQL recognizes the date format